# How to create a virtual machine programmatically?

Tags: python, virtual-machine

I'm trying to find a way to run .exe application in python (I mean making virtual box where you can run .exe programs). And when you run the application its will only affect the folder where python script is.

Comment: Are you asking how to run an executable from a python program or how to isolate its effects, or how to create a VM from a python program?

Comment: how to create a VM from a python program

Comment: Did my solution answer your question @R.A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ADD main.py .
ADD the.exe
CMD [ "python", "main.py"]
```

main.py

```py
import os
os.startfile("/the.exe")
```

Build

`docker build -t isolatedExe:latest .`

Run

`docker run isolatedExe:latest`

Next interact with the container by using

`docker exec -i -t <image> /bin/bash`

> Note: Find the image id with `docker ps`